# Convert a div within a div to inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert a `div` element within a `div` to `inline` but its not working as expected.

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="price-results">
    <div id="price"><div>Unit Price</div><div>5</div></div>
    <div id="qty"><div>Quantity</div><div>2</div></div>
    <div id="total"><div>TotalPrice</div><div>10</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #price,#qty{
        display:inline
    }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqTDq/)

Comment: How about `float: left;`?

Comment: If you want the inner divs to be inline then I would switch them to `span`s, which unlike divs are inline by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #price-results div{
        display:inline
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the [comment before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994065/convert-a-div-within-a-div-to-inline#answer-23994193).

Apart form that, your CSS needs to target the  inside the container like this:

```
    #price div,
    #qty div,
    #total div{
        display:inline
    }
```

… see this [fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqTDq/4/).

Some other notes on your HTML + CSS:

1. you should consider using classes instead of IDs
2. You could also
   target the elements by a single descendant rule like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqTDq/6/))

```
    #price-results > div div {
        display:inline
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css like below

```
#price, #qty{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This can be shorted by just using `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `float:left` instead of `display:inline`

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tnlkz)

Answer (score 0):

Why nesting so many divs unnecessarilly. Its not compulsary to include every element in div. This works fine :-

```
<div id="price-results">
<div id="price">Unit Price 5</div>
<div id="qty">Quantity 2</div>
<div id="total">TotalPrice 10</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qqTDq/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 *,div{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   display:inline;
  }

 #price,#qty{
     display:inline;
     border:1px solid red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

DIVs are block-level elements by default. I would switch the inner-DIVs to SPANs, which are inline by default:

```
<div id="price-results">
    <div id="price"><span>Unit Price</span> <span>5</span></div>
    <div id="qty"><span>Quantity</span> <span>2</span></div>
    <div id="total"><span>TotalPrice</span> <span>10</span></div>
</div>
```

---

If your intention is to align the numbers then I would switch to a `table`.